# Design patterns for QlikView apps

Tags: design-patterns, business-intelligence, qlikview

I come from a .NET background, where the gang of four design patterns for OOP are very useful to make code more debuggable, readable and reusable.

I am new to the QlikView environment now, and parts of the development that I have seen so far seem about as reusable as an Excel spreadsheet. Are there established guidelines for QlikView (or perhaps for BI dashboards) to accomplish debuggability, readability and reusability a similar spirit as the GOF patterns? Or is this area too young for such trends to have developed yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing that I've seen to anything like that for QlikView has been the Deployment Framework.

https://community.qlik.com/blogs/theqlikviewblog/2013/11/15/introducing-the-qlikview-deployment-framework

Beyond that, you'll see common models across documents (star or snowflake schemas) that mimic how other BI tools work.

Good luck!

Comment: I get the impression that QlikView has not made enough progress in this area to warrant the kind of answer I want. So for now, this is the best answer. I hope that in the years to come, better design patterns develop.